# How do I prevent the random alignment of the instructions during debugging using gdb? Even tried turning off the optimization with -O0 in gcc

Tags: c, assembly, debugging, x86, gcc

I have started with the book 'Hacking: The art of exploitation!'. I know some of you might suggest that it's pretty old... But I think great buildings withstand due to their strong foundational base. So, I have to get into what happened back then in x86, then only can move onto x86-64. So, simply reading the book without any hands on, won't help me much.

The book is leading me through some basics of debugging. So, it started with a hello world program.

**Source Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        puts("Hello, world!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I compiled using,**

```
gcc -g pg20.c -o pg20.out -m32 -O0 -fno-delayed-branch\
```

as, suggested by our beloved GPT Sir to disable any sort of compilation optimization.
(-m32 is to compile in x86 format as I am on a x86-64 CPU while the rest followed are for disabling any optimization)

But still while debugging the next 10 instructions in gdb, with
x/10i $eip
the problem still persists. The instructions are all out of order compared to how the source code is written.

Please help me out! Really frustrated! Not getting the hang of reading this wonderful book.

**How it should be as per the book**,

```
0x804838b <main+23>: cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0x9
0x804838f <main+27>: jle 0x8048393 <main+31>
0x8048391 <main+29>: jmp 0x80483a6 <main+50>
0x8048393 <main+31>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048484
0x804839a <main+38>: call 0x80482a0 <printf@plt>
0x804839f <main+43>: lea eax,[ebp-4]
0x80483a2 <main+46>: inc DWORD PTR [eax]
0x80483a4 <main+48>: jmp 0x804838b <main+23>
0x80483a6 <main+50>: leave
0x80483a7 <main+51>: ret
```

**But how my debugged lines look,**

```
   0x565561b1 <main+36>:        jmp    0x565561c9 <main+60>
   0x565561b3 <main+38>:        sub    esp,0xc
   0x565561b6 <main+41>:        lea    eax,[ebx-0x1fec]
   0x565561bc <main+47>:        push   eax
   0x565561bd <main+48>:        call   0x56556040 <puts@plt>
   0x565561c2 <main+53>:        add    esp,0x10
   0x565561c5 <main+56>:        add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x1
   0x565561c9 <main+60>:        cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x9
   0x565561cd <main+64>:        jle    0x565561b3 <main+38>
   0x565561cf <main+66>:        mov    eax,0x0
```

i.e. completely out of order. I don't know what is happening!

Comment: Welcome to the community. I think using an older version of gcc might be the easiest solution for you.

Comment: I agree with @SirMuffington and would recommend you do some research to figure out why your debug output functions very similarly to the books.  It will help you in the long run.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip! Really appreciate that! But unfortunately tried it even with gcc-4.3.2 but still the same issue! But the catch is book was published back in 2008 and even this version too! So, I can give it a try with few other older versions! But I am unable to install older versions. Even for this one I had to install an older version of ubuntu which really stressed me out. So, can you please suggest me some place or any such discussion forum where I can go and give a try to on how to get some other older versions installed without much of boring installation and deletion?

Comment: Usually compilers get optimized and it's machine code output changes. Maybe the author also used optimization REMOVING flags? You should check for that in your book.

Comment: Ya! I was suggested same by GPT-3! The above code provided is applied without optimizations only. Used the flag "-O0 -fno-delayed-branch". If I am missing something more, please guide me through then! And ya really thank you for taking some time out from you precious hours. I really appreciate that! God Bless!